# Lightning Basic Page

Tags: lightning

I am very new to Lightning I want to start with a simple Lightning page. Please let me know how to create a simple Account input page and once I click save button it should save in the database.

This will be very helpful for me to start with.

Comment: Many resources exists online, I would start with trailhead or lightning guide.

Answer (score 1):

You can go through the "Develop for Lightning Experience" trail on Trailhead: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trails/lex_dev

It helps you start from the very basics to little more complex code, and its actually really fun.

Answer (score 0):

Please check salesforce documention and trailhead thats best way to learn salesforce lighning

Please check this link:

https://www.greytrix.com/blogs/salesforce/2016/08/30/save-records-via-lightning-app/

read salesforce documention: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/intro_framework.htm

and also check sfdc monkey for lightning you will learn a lot of things:

http://sfdcmonkey.com/

Please bookmark those links and it will be very useful to you.

If you are facing any issue in saving account records please post the question community members will help you.